# How can I create an iCloud mail rule to forward emails to an address and move them out of the inbox?

Tags: icloud, email, mail-rules

In iCloud, there are rules to forward matching emails to an address and to move matching emails to a mailbox, however I can't find a way of forwarding matching emails to an address and then moving them out of the inbox.  Adding two rules (one to forward the emails and one to move the emails) doesn't work since only the first rule is applied.  I'm looking for a server-side rule as I don't want to have to keep my Mac running to prevent being notified about these emails and having them appear in my inbox on my phone.

Comment: I have no experience with iCloud email. But perhaps you could accomplish the same result by reversing the order of the actions. Create a rule that moves all matching emails to a new mailbox that you've created, and create another rule that forwards the contents of that newly-created mailbox (by definition, the "matching" emails) to the desired address. That way, they will be out of the inbox, and will have been forwarded.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work — the rules are only applied to new messages arriving in the inbox.